# Merging two lists of dataframes using R

Tags: r, list, merge, dataframe

I would like to merge two lists of dataframes according to a common id variable, consider the following example

```
set.seed(1)
mylist1=data.frame(id=sample(paste0("id",sample(1:5,10,T))),var1=sample(letters[1:26],10,T),stringsAsFactors=F);mylist1=split(mylist1,mylist1$id)
set.seed(2)
mylist2=data.frame(id=sample(paste0("id",sample(1:5,10,T))),var2=sample(LETTERS[1:26],10,T),stringsAsFactors=F);mylist2=split(mylist2,mylist2$id)

mylist1
# $id1
# id     var1
# id1    d
# 
# $id2
# id     var1
# id2    f
# id2    g
# id2    w
# etc.

mylist2
# $id1
# id     var2
# id1    V
# id1    D
# id1    J
# 
# $id3
# id     var2
# id3    K
# id3    J
# id3    Z
# etc.
```

The resulting list of dataframes should look like

```
# $id1
# id  var1 var2
# id1 d    V
# id1 d    D
# id1 d    J

# $id2
# id  var1 var2
# id2 f    NA
# id2 g    NA
# id2 w    NA
# etc.
```

Do yo know how I could do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simultaneously merge multiple data.frames in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list)

Comment: In this case you could marge data.frame's and then split the resulting one into a list

Comment: Your input data and the one you showed is not correct

Comment: Try `Map(merge, mylist1, mylist2,MoreArgs=list(by='id', all=TRUE))`

Comment: In the example, the lengths of mylist1 and mylist2 are different ie. 5 vs. 4

Comment: @jeremycg. This is not the same question as the output should be a list of dataframes and not a data frame. akrun, I corrected the code, sorry for the typo

Comment: @Clement In the examples, I find some ids are not present in mylist1 , which is found in mylist2.  How do you want to deal those cases

Comment: @akrun, this is the case of `id2` which is not present in `mylist2`. In this case, the resulting dataframe (in the list) should take `NA` values for `id2`. i.e. example for an illustration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` to do this.  From the example dataset, it is clear that only some `list` elements are common to both (based on the names of the list elements).

Our first step would be to get all the `unique` names in each of the `list` using `union`.  We subset the first ('lst1') and second `list` ('lst2') with those names ('nm1').  If there is a missing element, it will be a `NULL` element for that position.

```
nm1 <- union(names(mylist1), names(mylist2))
lst1 <- mylist1[nm1]
lst2 <- mylist2[nm1]
```

Now, we change the `NULL` values in each `list` by creating a 'data.frame' for that position.  We can use `if/else` to do this on a `lapply` loop.

```
lst1 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) if(is.null(x)) 
                         data.frame(id=NA, var1=NA) else x)
lst2 <- lapply(lst2, function(x) if(is.null(x))
                        data.frame(id=NA, var2=NA) else x)
```

After that, we can `merge` the two `lists` using `Map`.  The corresponding elements of the `lists` are `merge`d.  Instead of using anonymous function, we can make use of `MoreArgs` to specify the extra arguments that may be needed for the `merge`.

```
Map(merge, lst1, lst2,MoreArgs=list(by='id', all=TRUE))
#$id1
#   id var1 var2
#1 id1    d    V
#2 id1    d    D
#3 id1    d    J

#$id2
#    id var1 var2
#1  id2    f   NA
#2  id2    g   NA
#3  id2    w   NA
#4 <NA> <NA>   NA

#$id3
#   id var1 var2
#1 id3    y    K
#2 id3    y    J
#3 id3    y    Z

#$id4
#   id var1 var2
#1 id4    a    D
#2 id4    i    D

#$id5
#   id var1 var2
#1 id5    q    R
#2 id5    q    M
#3 id5    q    D
#4 id5    k    R
#5 id5    k    M
#6 id5    k    D
#7 id5    j    R
#8 id5    j    M
#9 id5    j    D
```